# Currency conversion issue during Java8 --- > Java17 migration

Tags: java-8, currency, number-formatting, java-17

`

```
public class TestCurrency {

    public static void main(String []args) {
        int decimalPrecision=0;
        String currencySymbol="إ.د";
        String dfSymbolReplacePattern = "د.إ.\u200F";

        Locale locale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("ar").setRegion("AE").build();
        final NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
        final DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) nf;

        df.setMinimumFractionDigits(decimalPrecision);
        df.setMaximumFractionDigits(decimalPrecision);
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

        final String positivePrefix = df.getPositiveSuffix().replace(dfSymbolReplacePattern, currencySymbol);
        final String positiveSuffix = df.getPositivePrefix().replace(dfSymbolReplacePattern, currencySymbol);
        final String negativePrefix = df.getNegativeSuffix().replace(dfSymbolReplacePattern, currencySymbol);
        final String negativeSuffix = df.getNegativePrefix().replace(dfSymbolReplacePattern, currencySymbol);
        df.setPositivePrefix(positivePrefix);
        df.setNegativePrefix(negativePrefix);
        df.setPositiveSuffix(positiveSuffix);
        df.setNegativeSuffix(negativeSuffix);

        System.out.println("Arabic Amount is: "+df.format(10.0));
    }

}
```

`

Java 8:
Arabic Amount is: 10إ.د
Java 17:
Arabic Amount is:  إ.د١٠

Want to keep format from Java8 while running on Java17

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what changes in localization and internationalization were taken between Java 11 and Java 17, but I have found a simple workaround after some brief experiments. Follow the steps:

1. Change the locale language to English (`"en"`) and keep the United Arab Emirates region (`"AE"`):

   ```java
   Locale locale = new.Locale.Builder().setLanguage("en").setRegion("AE").build();
   ```

   This results in the following result: `Arabic Amount is: 10AED`
2. Change the replacement defined by `dfSymbolReplacePattern` from `"د.إ.\u200F"` to `"AED"`.

   ```java
   String dfSymbolReplacePattern = "AED";
   ```

   Now the `"AED"` currency symbol would be replaced: `Arabic Amount is: 10إ.د`